# Why won't my nav element go to the center or change style?

Tags: css, html, margin, nav

I am trying to get my nav element to center but it won't work for the older versions of Internet Explorer or Chrome. It also won't change style. How can I get this to center and change? Here is the code:

The nav:

```
<nav id="Nav">
    <a href="TMR Library.html">Library</a> |
    <a href="TMR Contact.html">Contact</a> |
    <a href="TMR About.html">About</a>
</nav>
```

The CSS

```
#Nav {
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #22b14c;
    font-family: "Papyrus";
}
```

Comment: I think @user2784439 was thinking that `margin:0 auto;` would center the `nav` element; however, there is no `width` specified.

@user2784439, without a `width` specified, there is no room for the margins to extend to the edges because `block` elements such as `nav` have `100%` width by default.

Comment: A menu is typically created in a list. Semantically, this is more logical as well. Make a `ul` with `li`-items that contain the links. This way, it's also much easier to create sub menus.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many ways to centre elements:

Margin way:

With a set width or `display: inline-block;` you can use:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

`text-align` way:

With a set width or `display: inline-block;` you can add this to the parent:

```
text-align: center;
```

Absolute way:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: width/2;
```

or

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(0, -50%);
```

Also don't worry too much about ie7 and below as the the majority of people use higher versions of ie or a different browser though this should work up until ie6

Another thing to watch out for is that you want to use a ul for your navbar. I know, from experience, that it works fine though if you ever want to add a drop-down to the navbar then it is much harder.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below:

```
text-align: center;
```

instead of

```
margin 0 auto;
```

[**Sample Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/8nGNT/)

**Note:** My assumption was that you did not want to specify a width. Otherwise, you can just use the `margin` as already stated in the other answers.

**EDIT:** To use the `<nav>` and other HTML5 tags with lower version of IE, you can use the HTML5shiv.js (by including the below script).

```
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.2/html5shiv.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: thanks this got it working in chrome but it still doesn't work in older Internet explorer versions nor does it change font etc. How can i do this?

Comment: @user2784439: Older IE versions, I don't have so give me sometime to check on them (it should work). The font works properly in the fiddle. Did you have a look at it?

Comment: yes i had a look everything is fine in chrome, but it doesn't work in IE, nothing seems to work :(

Comment: If you're viewing the JSFiddle in IE7 or below (possibly other versions of IE), then it won't look right because JSFiddle itself doesn't load on those browsers.

Comment: First things first - `nav` is not supported in IE9-  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp

Comment: @ılǝ: Agreed mate, please see my comment in J McFee's answer. For a moment, I took it for granted :(

Comment: well that explains it, should i use a list instead?

Comment: @ılǝ: By the way, this method does work in IE9 (IE9 Standards mode). Less than 9 it doesn't work. I would suggest the use of html5shiv.js

Comment: @user2784439: I say it depends on what you want to do. If you want to write code for future, then use `<nav>` and use html5shiv to make it compatible with lower versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a block element it will spread 100% across the page, try giving it a width

```
#Nav {
display:Block;
width:500px;
margin:0 auto;
font-size: 40px;
color: #22b14c;
font-family: "Papyrus";
}
```

Comment: thanks i got it working for chrome but it still wont do any of the styling for older Internet explorer versions

Comment: use display:block for older versions, since nav is an HTML5 element you need to set it to be a block level element in order to display properly

Comment: @JMcFee: I think you are spot on with that comment. I did not think of it (took it for granted :D).

Comment: what version of IE are you trying test on?

Comment: version 8, its not going to the center or changing the style

Answer (score 0):

`margin: 0 auto;` has no meaning without specifying the width.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
  #Nav 
  {
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     width: 12em;
     font-size: 40px;
     color: #22b14c;
     font-family: "Papyrus";
  }
```